# How to get page properties using sling model in aem 6.3?

Tags: sling-models

I am trying to get page properties using Sling Models in AEM 6.3 but always I am getting null.

```
resultsRootPath = getCurrentPage().getProperties().get("ResultsRootPath", String.class);
```

Path of property:

```
/components/content/results/cq:dialog/content/items/column/items/ResultsRootPath
```

Could you please let me know the correct ways to property value using Sling Models?

Comment: Is this a multi-valued property?

Comment: No, it's a single valued property.

Comment: Your property path looks like a component dialogue path. Can you check in jcr if the property exists and if the page property dialogue contains this property?

Comment: Yes, the property ResultsRootPath exits in the below page and same component model trying to get ResultsRootPath property /content/brcd/uk/en/insto/search-results/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/search_results

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
@Model(adaptables = {SlingHttpServletRequest.class,Resource.class})
public class MyCustomModel{

    @Inject
    private InheritanceValueMap pageProperties;

    @Inject
    private ValueMap properties;

    @PostConstruct
    public void activate() {
        String pageString = pageProperties.getInherited("myproperty", "default"); //InheritanceValueMap gives pageProperties Value Map and getInherited is used to fetch a particular property.
    }
```

Refer this for more info:
http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/valuemap-and-his-friend/

Answer (score 1):

an alternative to these other options but might be simpler.
the models know what page they are based on the SlingHttpServletRequest in the @Model section

```
@Model(
        adaptables = {Resource.class, SlingHttpServletRequest.class, SlingHttpServletResponse.class},
        defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL
)
public class ModelClassName {

    @Inject
    private Page currentPage;
```

The @Inject private page currentPage will automatically grab the page and allow you access to all the properties etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your model class you can create a field like this:

```
@Model(adaptables = Page.class)
public class ResultsPageModel {

    @Inject
    @Via("contentResource")
    @Named("ResultsRootPath")
    private Resource resultsRootPath;
}
```

or

```
@Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class)
public class ResultsPageModel {

    @Inject
    @Via("resource")
    @Named("ResultsRootPath")
    private Resource resultsRootPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To take advantage of [injector specific annotation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#injector-specific-annotations), the better way will be:

```
@Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class)
public class MyModel {
  @ValueMapValue
  private String ResultsRootPath;

  public String getResultsRootPath(){ return ResultsRootPath; }
}
```

To mention, please use camel case for properties asin resultsRootPath.